# how to dynamically get all the checkboxes checked?

Tags: android

I have 16 checkboxes and i am dynamically trying to get the once that are checked i have numbered them from checkBox1-checkbox16 in my layout.

The code i am using is as below

```
package com.example.test;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Compare1 extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.commac1);
        // setdesign();
        checkbox();
    }

    private void checkbox() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int a=1;a<17;a++){
            String cb="checkBox"+a;
            int id=getResources().getIdentifier(cb, "id", getPackageName());
            CheckBox cb1=(CheckBox) findViewById(id);
            if(cb1.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "you selected" +cb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }}}}
```

This does not seem to be working.Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: You need to hook up .setOnCheckedChangeListener to the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your class (based on @FMontano's suggestion)

```
public class Compare1 extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ...
```

and then try this method 1:

```
CheckBox cb1 = findViewById(id);
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //Toast.makeText ...
        }
    });
```

Or this method 2:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch(buttonView.getId()){
               case R.id.checkbox1:
                 //your toast
               break;
               case R.id.checkbox2:
                 //your toast
               break;
               case R.id.checkbox3:
                //your toast
               break;

            }

}
```

and call it to use like this

```
CheckBox cb1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Don't forget to make your Activity implement OnCheckedChangeListener:

`public class Compare1 extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: @FMontano Yes! Edited to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Using IsabelHM suggestion, you would end up with you would end up with something looking like this:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Compare1 extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.commac1);
    // setdesign();
    checkbox();
}

private void checkbox() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int a=1;a<17;a++){
        String cb="checkBox"+a;
        int id=getResources().getIdentifier(cb, "id", getPackageName());
        CheckBox cb1=(CheckBox) findViewById(id);
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); 
    }
}

/// Will be called by all the checkboxes
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch(buttonView.getId()){
           case R.id.checkbox1:
             //your toast
           break;
           case R.id.checkbox2:
             //your toast
           break;
           case R.id.checkbox3:
            //your toast
           break;
           ...
           case R.id.checkbox16:
            //your toast
           break;
        }

}
}
```